# How to check for a value in an array for a specific string found in another array?

Tags: java, eclipse

I need to use the input from what the user entered in the Java Scanner and then figure out if that specific input is accepted as part of a check if there is enough in an inventory array. Also the specific value of the int inventory array has to match with the string items array. For example, for item "ScrewDriver" there is a quantity of 500.

This is program is for a homework assignment and I am stuck on a step where I have to find out how many of an item the user is wanting to buy. If the input amount is more than there is in int[] inventory then I have to let the user know and quit the program. But if I do have enough in inventory then I have to show the final bill amount. I think I was properly able to ask the user for how many they want but I am stuck on using that information for my next method. So far I have only been able to get the purchaseAmount to work but I can not figure out the finalBillAmount. What am I doing incorrectly?

```
String[] items = {"Hammer", "Wrench", "Pliers", "Saw", "ScrewDriver" };
    double[] prices = {1.99, 2.99, 3.99, 4.99, 5.99};
    int[] inventory = {100, 200, 300, 400, 500};

    String itemAsked = askUserForItem(items);
    String itemInfo = showItemInfo(items, prices, inventory, itemAsked);
    int itemAmount = purchaseAmount(items, inventory, itemAsked, itemInfo);
    int finalAmount = finalBillAmount(items, inventory, itemAsked, itemInfo, itemAmount);

private static int purchaseAmount(String[] items, int[] inventory, String itemAsked,
        String itemInfo) {
    int itemAmount = 0;
    Scanner myS = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.printf("\nHow many would you like to purchase? -> ");
    itemAmount = myS.nextInt();
    return itemAmount;
}
```

I expect the output to show the amount available and to show the final bill amount, "Your total bill is: $ %s". Also, if the items are unavailable then the output should be "Sorry we only have Inventory : %s of Item: %s"

Comment: Have you got certain requirements for the assignment that mean you're doing it like this, as opposed to creating objects to represent the tools and their prices/stock?

Comment: We have not started with objects yet.

Comment: Then you need to pass around the index of the item that the user selected, and use it to get the price + quantity then, if quantity does not exceed stock, multiply the two and return that.

Answer (score 0):

I will help with the logic and leave the rest to you.
In regards to the method: 
`finalBillAmount(items, inventory, itemAsked, itemInfo, itemAmount);`
We can see that we have a variety of parameters to work with. To begin, we structure a for-loop to see which index the item is at, with respect to the item array.

```
int index = 0;
for(int i = 0;i<items.length;i++){
     if(itemAsked.equals(items[i]){
          index = i;
}
```

Next, we compare the amount of itemsAsked with the amount in inventory:

```
if(itemAmount>inventory[index]){
     System.out.println("Sorry, we don't have that many of "+item[index]);
     return 0;
}
else{

//I would need to see how your showItemInfo method works in order to compute the bill.
}
```

I hope that helps!